In Port Royal, if I have a jester and I bust, do I get a coin?
In Port Royal, if you draw 2 ships of the same color, you bust and "your turn ends", and you don't get the "trade and hire" phase.
If you have a jester in your tableau, do you get a coin?
In my gaming group, we have a disagreement, whether:

everyone with a jester gets a coin whenever someone busts
other players, but not the active player
nobody

If nobody gets a coin on a bust, then jesters are mostly pointless. But some people say that the first option makes them too powerful.

Everyone with a jester gets a coin, official statement from the publisher. https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1203814/jester-question

Yes, you get 1 coin per Jester in your personal display.
The important part of the rules is "all players with a Jester in their personal display gain 1 coin."
This has been clarified by the publisher on Board Game Geek (as well as the designer)

rule page 3 at the top of the left column:
"... but ALL players with a jester in their personal display gain 1 coin."
The same on the last page - Jester (last sentence):
"... Should a player forfeit his turn during a Phase 1 Discover and the second Phase is skipped, ALL players with a jester gain 1 coin."
All players means all players. Not just all the other players except the active player :-).
Hope you have much fun with the game
Klaus Ottmaier
Editor Pegasus Spiele

